# Invoking Java Methods from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java

I got a case like this:

I got a java class with the following code:

```
private static final int INVALID_PARAM = -1;
private static final int AGE = 1;
private static final int BLOOD_PREASURE = 3;

@GET
@Path("/execute")
public String execute(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
    try {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        engine.eval(getSrc(req.getServletContext().getRealPath("js/boot.js")));
        engine.eval(getSrc(req.getServletContext().getRealPath("js/test.js")));

        Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;

        Function<Integer, Object> fn = (arg) -> {
            ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
            ResteasyWebTarget rtarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/DSS-war/rest/bl");
            BlRest rest = rtarget.proxy(BlRest.class);
            switch(arg) {
            case AGE:
                int age = rest.age();
                client.close();
                return age;
            case BLOOD_PREASURE:                
                int bloodPreasure = rest.bloodPreasure();
                client.close();
                return bloodPreasure;
        }
            return INVALID_PARAM;
        };

        invocable.invokeFunction("init", fn);

        Object res = invocable.invokeFunction("f", 5);

        return res.toString();

    }catch(

ScriptException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch(
NoSuchMethodException e)
{
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

return"Error";
}
```

Also a boot.js file:

```
var dss;
var AGE = 1;
var INVALID_PARAM = -1;
var BLOOD_PREASURE = 1;


function init(d) {
    dss = d;
}
```

Also a test.js file:

```
function f(x) {
    var age = dss(AGE);
    return age;
}

function f2(x) {
    var bloodPreasure = dss(BLOOD_PREASURE);
    return bloodPreasure;
}

function c(callback) {
    return callback("from callback");
}
```

Also an interface

```
@GET
@Path("/age")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public int age();



@GET
@Path("/blood_preasure")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public int bloodPreasure();
```

Also a class that implements that interface

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("/bl")
public class Blulinea implements BlRest{
@Override
public int age() {
    return 65;
}
@Override
public int bloodPreasure() {
    return 150;
}
```

}

all that works through a href link on a html page

Ok...now, i first had just the f function in the test.js file....and called it from the execute function in the session bean...and it worked all, once I pressed the link, it showed 65, for age...

Now, i added a new function f2, for blood preasure....and added all the parts about it to the code....
Once done, I called the f2 function with the following code:

```
Object res = invocable.invokeFunction("f2", 5);
```

witch I placed in the execute method...but when i pressed the a href link on the page, it showed again 65 (age)
then i tried to find a solution, and I found out that, either the function f nor f2 witch i called in the execute method didnt matter....but what matter was the constant i declared on top  of the file....

```
private static final int AGE = 1;
private static final int BLOOD_PREASURE = 3;
```

these 2 parameters, decide which function is been called...

if age is smaller then blood_preasure then the age function will be called, else the blood_preasure function will be called....ofc its bc of the switch case...

but i need to be able to call the right function like this

```
Object res = invocable.invokeFunction("f", 5);
```

or

```
Object res = invocable.invokeFunction("f2", 5);
```

not though the lower value on the constant....in the switch
Ofc, if I change the values to 2 or higher, the switch ll give me -1

And the arg parameter in the lambda function is always 1...mby u can show me a way to change it with the invokeFunction

I hope u got my problem and can help me...

Comment: what does "Ofc" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer...in the boot file are this lines:

```
var AGE = 1;
var INVALID_PARAM = -1;
var BLOOD_PREASURE = 1;
```

and there is the problem, it should be AGE=1 and BLOOD_PREASURE=2

then it works...